# Neo4j data modeling query

Tags: neo4j

I am working on a project (platform) where I am using neo4j to make connections between users. There are following different ways where user can connect to other users on the platform.

1. When a user logs in with Facebook, I get his mutual friends who are already using our platform. There I make a connection in my graph database by creating a new node (current user) and make connections with all existing nodes whom he knows through facebook.
2. One user also connects with other user if both are staying in same society/community. So the use case is, once a user updates his residential address (society name, city) than I make a query in graph db and get all nodes who also stay in the same society and create this new user with those nodes with relationship name "Same society".
3. Same was user might be connected with other user if both users study in same college or school. I make a connection between two nodes with relationship "Same college/school".

What is the best way to model the above problem in neo4j?  If I do a query in DB to get all the relationship types and shortest path of all the relationships between given two nodes, which model will be optimized for this type of query?

Answer (score 0):

1. Simply create a relationship between users

   `(user)-[:FRIEND_OF]-(user)`

   Relationships in neo4j are always directional, but you can ignore the direction because, in this case, it doesn't make much sense. There is no performance penalty for traversing a relationship "backwards".
2. Create a node representing your society/community and link all users living there to that node. This has several benefits:

   - when you add new user to a community you only create one relationship (compared to linking the user directly to all users, which is N relationships), same goes for removing user from community.
   - you can create different relationships between the user and community

   `(user)-[:LIVES]-(community1)
    (user)-[:WORKS]-(community2)`
3. This is essentially the same as no. 2. You can differentiate between types of communities (schools, etc..) by having different labels/properties.

Finding a shortest path between two nodes in this model will give you their closest connection, the kind of "know via something". You may limit the path by relationship type/community type etc.